# "Calm down" VS "Get calm"

Tags: verbs, idioms, expressions, idioms-in-context

> - After a series of bad events, my life is just ............. and I want to maintain that peace.

**a.getting calm** (this is the correct answer here, but I need to make sure whether there is a better idiom / expression here in natural English. 
**b. calming down** (I think this idiom is only applicable to a person. i.e. we can only calm someone down and we cannot utilize it when it comes to say a situation. However I have my doubts here.)

I was wondering if you could let me know about it.

Comment: *I/You need to calm down* is normal idiomatic English. *I/You need to get calm* is syntactically valid, and perfectly understandable, but it's not something a native speaker would normally say. This would be the same as, for example *Please sit down* (where we might say *Please be seated*, but not often *Please get seated*). Just because ***get*** is very flexible in English doesn't mean it works idiomatically *everywhere*.

Comment: "...my life is just calming down" is perfectly colloquial. Yes, we can also calm ourselves down and calm other people down, but things too calm down. [This NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=calm+the+situation+down%2Ccalming+the+situation+down%2Csituation+has+calmed+down&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccalm%20the%20situation%20down%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccalming%20the%20situation%20down%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csituation%20has%20calmed%20down%3B%2Cc0) shows "calm the situation down" in common use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As FumbleFingers has stated, the expression **calm down** is often used in relation to people.

It is also normal, but less common, to use the expression **calming down** regarding a situation, and a situation is what you are describing. Here is a typical example:

> The R&D budget situation is calming down, as well - *[Governemnt Laboratory Technology Transfer, Sally A Rood, 2018](https://www.google.co.id/books/edition/Government_Laboratory_Technology_Transfe/9vhKDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22situation%20is%20calming%20down%22&pg=PT75&printsec=frontcover)*

In my opinion, **calming down** is more natural than **getting calm** when used to describe a situation.